# Any APIs to get list of consumer groups created in Azure IotHub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I'm fairly new to Azure IotHub and doing some POCs on it. As part of that, I'm trying to get the list of existing consumer groups that are created on the IotHub.

However, I couldn't find any APIs in the documentation that list the consumer groups currently listening on an Azure IotHub?

Is there anything I've missed or there aren't any such APIs that can be used?

Thank you!

References : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Azure API to get the consumer groups of the Iot Hub - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/resourceprovider/list-d2c-consumer-groups